# Preview File before uploading in proper way.(React&Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, file, react-hooks

I am trying to preview the image file before uploading.

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File>();
const [preview, setPreview] = useState<string>();

<form action="" onSubmit={onUploadImage}>
                  <input
                    name="file"
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                      if (!event.target.files) return
                      setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
                      setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
                    }} />
                    <img src={preview} alt="preview" />
                </form>
```

This code above is working.

My problem I would like to solve is finding better way to preview the image file.

As my code, I set `selectedFile` as type of **File** like `useState<File>();`
It was not allowed to set `selectedFile` to img tag `<img src={selectedFile} alt="preview" />` because of type errror.
That is why I made a new state `const [preview, setPreview] = useState<string>();` to preview image instead of using `selectedFile` since src should be string. But this is a hassle way to set the state twice.

If you have better idea not to use double states like my code, I would really appreciate.
If possible, I would like to keep to use `useState<File>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first set the default of `selectedFile` to be `null`,
then set `src` of image directly :

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);

<input
   onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if (!event.target.files) return
      setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
   }}
/>
<img src={selectedFile === null ? '' : URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)} alt="preview" />
```

Comment: Adding null value to default ! That makes sense. Appreciated.

Comment: I still got the error "Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: I've updated the solution's code `src={selectedFile === null ? '' : URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)}` .. instead of `src={selectedFile !== null && URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)}`